# Efficient approximation for find all the nodes and edges which match with some sub-tree in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, graph-isomorphism

Let's suppose that I have a big digraph *D* and a small tree *T* (small w.r.t *D*), both directed, *D* can be connected or not, but *T* is connected.

Here an example:
Let's say that *D* is as follow:
[image]
And *T* is the following tree:
[image]

So I would like to identify the nodes and edges in *D* that can potentially match with *T*. In other words, I would like to color in red the set of nodes and edges that participate in any isomorphism from *T* to *D*. Something like this:
[image]

What efficient algorithm can I use? I was reading about sub-graph isomorphism, but in my case, I don't have necessarily the label of edges, and I'm worried about the complexity. Are there other approaches?

About the output of the algorithm, the node `P`, for example, is red because don't exist any way that `P` with a combination of all their neighbor's nodes match with *T* due to his pattern which needs 4 consecutive nodes with edges pointing to the same direction, like a chain.

Comment: If you want to *list* every such correspondence, I think you can't do better than about $O(2^{n/2})$ time, because you could produce an output that big.  Specifically: When $D$ contains $n$ numbered vertices and an edge from every vertex to every lower-numbered vertex, and $T$ is a path of $n/2$ vertices, then there is a correspondence for every element in a [Sperner family](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806691/big-oh-for-size-of-a-sperner-family)).

Comment: If you only want to *count* the number of such correspondences, you might be able to do better.  I would suggest trying to create a dynamic programming algorithm that computes $f(u, v)$, the number of subgraphs reachable from $u \in V(D)$ that are isomorphic to the subtree rooted at $v \in V(T)$.

Comment: So is your problem the subgraph isomorphism problem or not?  I don't know what you mean by "identify nodes and edges that can potentially match" (potentially match?  under what conditions does it count as a match?  what does potentially mean?).  Can you state the problem more clearly?  You've told us what the inputs are.  What do you want the algorithm to output?

Comment: Well, I don't know the algorithm, that's my question. Should I use an algorithm like subgraph isomorphism or it's possible to use other alternatives... I updated the post to explain the expected output.

Comment: From your edit it looks like you want to colour red the set of nodes and edges that do not participate in *any* isomorphism from $T$ to $D$.  Is that right?

Comment: yes! it's exactly that.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify.  Don't just leave clarifications in the comments.  We want people to be able to understand what you are asking without having to read the comments.

Comment: Please don't append "UPDATE:" and more stuff.  Instead, revise the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and remove the "UPDATE" markings.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.